# Gulp with browserify, tsify, and reactify?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, reactjs

I'm using `gulp` with `browserify` and `tsify` in a TypeScript project. The following is an extract from my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var browserified = function (filename, debug) {
  var b = browserify({
    entries: filename,
    debug: debug || false
  });
  b.plugin('tsify', {
    noImplicitAny: true,
    target: 'ES5'
  });
  b.transform('debowerify');
  return b.bundle();
};

gulp.task('rebuild', ['lint', 'less'], function() {
    var b = browserified ('./src/ts/main.ts', true);
    return buildSourceMaps (b);
});
```

This works so far. I want to extend this so I can `require` React JSX files. First I tried (from one of my TypeScript files):

```
import Test = require ('../jsx/Test.jsx');
```

This doesn't work, though, because `tsify` would complain as it looks for a TypeScript file `../jsx/Test.jsx.ts`. So I use the following hack:

```
declare var require: any;
var Test = require ('../jsx/Test.jsx');
```

If `Test.jsx` is plain vanilla JavaScript, this works. If `Test.jsx` contains TypeScript, it would fail, which is what I expect. So far, so clear.

Now I want to add `reactify` to my gulp tasks so I can use JSX in these files. *Here I am stuck!* I tried adding the following to the function `browserified` in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
b.plugin ('reactify', {
    extension: 'jsx'
});
```

I still get the following error when I call `gulp rebuild` when `Test.jsx` contains actual JSX:

```
Unexpected token <
```

Obviously, gulp chokes on the first JSX-specific term. I think gulp is trying to pass the JSX through the TypeScript compiler. Which isn't a surprise, since I can't think of a way how to tell `tsify` to ignore my .jsx files. I'm new to `gulp`, so I am a bit at a loss. Any ideas how to set up `gulp` to allow for TypeScript with all ***.ts*** files and JSX with all ***.jsx*** files?

Answer (score 0):

This is the gulp task I use for development. It uses `watchify` along with `browserify` and `reactify` to build your code, provide source mapping, and rebundle any changes you make on the fly. The `path.ENTRY_POINT` variable is the main component for your react app (often `app.js` or `main.js`).

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch(path.HTML, ['copy']);

   var watcher  = watchify(browserify({
       entries: [path.ENTRY_POINT],
       transform: [reactify],
       debug: true,
       cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true
   }));

   return watcher.on('update', function () {
       watcher.bundle()
           .pipe(source(path.OUT))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST_SRC))
       console.log('Updated');
   })
       .bundle()
       .pipe(source(path.OUT))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST_SRC));
});
```

I used this tutorial to set up my `gulpfile.js` and it provides a good explanation for every gulp task:
http://tylermcginnis.com/reactjs-tutorial-pt-2-building-react-applications-with-gulp-and-browserify/